# hsql bad sql grammar exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

I create an in memory table in the database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ERRORCONTEXT (
  eventId         INTEGER,
  processStartTsp TIMESTAMP,
  processEndTsp TIMESTAMP,
  errorStack LONGVARCHAR,
  tradeReference VARCHAR(30),
  integrationStatus  VARCHAR(50),
  integrationStatusDescription LONGVARCHAR
);
```

my insert script:

```
insert into ERRORCONTEXT (eventId,processStartTsp,processEndTsp,errorStack,tradeReference,integrationStatus,integrationStatusDescription) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

I have the above sql scripts for which I cannot insert into hsql db and getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO ERRORCONTEXT (eventId, processStartTsp,processEndTsp,errorStack,tradeReference,integrationStatus,integrationStatusDescription)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
```

My pojo which I insert is as follows:

```
public class TradeProcessingContext {

    private Long eventId;
    private String tradeReference;
    private LocalDateTime processStartTsp;
    private LocalDateTime processEndTsp;
    private String errorStack;
    private IntegrationStatus integrationStatus;
    private String integrationStatusDescription;


}
```

I dont understand where the incompatible type error is coming from. Sample data i am trying to insert is as followwss:

```
eventId=54611889, 
tradeReference=TRADE_REF-3033372, 
processStartTsp=2018-03-22T18:20:31.643, 
processEndTsp=2018-03-22T18:20:32.688, 
errorStack= (this is the full exception stack trace)
integrationStatus=SENT,
integrationStatusDescription=PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into aqapp.nvision_tradess(event_id, trade_reference, event_state, process_start_tsp,process_end_tsp,error_stack) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

integrationStatus => String value of my enum type

integrationStatusDescription => exception `getMessage()`

HSQL Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The underlying DAO method:

```
public boolean log(final TradeProcessingContext tc) {
    int affected = jdbcTemplate.update(SQLQueryHelper.getQuery(Queries.LOG_QUERY),
            tc.getEventId(),
            tc.getProcessStartTsp(),
            tc.getProcessEndTsp(),
            tc.getErrorStack(),
            tc.getTradeReference(),
            String.valueOf(tc.getIntegrationStatus()),
            String.valueOf(tc.getIntegrationStatusDescription())
    );
```

Comment: where are the values in your insert script?

Comment: give us sample data that you are trying to insert.

Comment: @anonyXmous added

Comment: What version of HSQLDB are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson 2.3.2

Comment: show the way you create the query object and add the params

Answer (score 0):

I needed to wrap the `LocalDateTime` variable with `java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(time);`

Comment: ... or upgrade to HSQLDB 2.4.0, which introduced support for `java.time.LocalDateTime` et al. in Java 8.

Comment: Also, be aware that converting a `java.time.LocalDateTime` to a `java.sql.Timestamp` will impose timezone rules that may alter the value. For example, `java.sql.Timestamp` cannot represent "2018-03-11T02:00:00" in the "America/Denver" timezone because that time simply does not exist in that timezone due to the switch over to daylight saving time.